# Open app when clicking push notification

Tags: java, firebase, ionic-framework, push-notification, ionic2

I have an Ionic app which receives push notifications via FCM. The problem is that when the app is not in the foreground and I click on the notification on the status bar,  the app won't open  (although the action from on('notification') is executed). This is my mobile app code:

```
this.pushNotifications.on('notification').subscribe((data: any) => {
  if (data.additionalData.foreground) {
    alert('Ai primit un mesaj nou');
  }
  this.events.publish("gotMessage");
});
```

Notice that `this.events.publish("gotMessage");` is executed.

And this is how I send the notification through Java:

```
Map body = DataMap.map(
    "registration_ids", tokens,
    "data", DataMap.map(
        "content-available", "1",
        "title", "Fmcg Reporter",
        "body", "Ai primit un mesaj nou",
        "sound", "default"
    ),
    "collapse_key", "FmcgReporter"
);

Map headers = DataMap.map(
   "Authorization", "key=" + key,
   "Content-Type", "application/json"
);

Strings.readMethodURL("POST", "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send", headers, Strings.toJSON(body));
```

Comment: what is the device platform - android?

Comment: did you try adding "click_action" into your "data" obj?

Comment: Yes, I use Android

Answer (score 0):

Make sure when you send push notification using your server you specify "click_action". Below is a working example from my node.js server:

```
// method: "POST",
//url: "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send",
    // get the key from Firebase console
    headers: { Authorization: `key=${fcmServerKey}` }, 
    json: {
        "notification": { 
            "title": "Message title",
            "body": "Message body",
            "click_action": "URL to your app?"
        },
        // userData is where your client stored the FCM token for the given user
        // it should be read from the database
        "to": userData.fcmRegistrationKey
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Or maybe I'm adding somethign wrong to "click_action". I've added my ap id from config.xml. Where can I find the url to the app?

Comment: Hey Alex so your app is installed on a real device correct? You will need to add and use special schema for the url. I can see if i can find it